# concurrent queries in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datatable, phpmyadmin

I have a transaction table, which has the attributes: id, description, amount, balance, datetime.

To keep the amount updated, for each new transaction record, the balance of the last transaction is consulted and added to the amount of the new transaction to obtain the new balance.

[image]

[image]

Is it possible that queries are executed simultaneously, such that, for the new transaction record, it takes the same balance as before the new transactions?

I'm new to this, thanks for helping!

Comment: what is the frequency of the transaction? can you also share the sql code you tried?

Comment: transactions are highly frequent, since they work with a certain amount that is added to the balance for each view of a public post and a small remuneration is added for each view, which is the record of the transaction to which I refer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update Balance column automatically in a balance ledger for different Customer IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62962518/update-balance-column-automatically-in-a-balance-ledger-for-different-customer-i)